# VBA Deleting named ranges. Get #NAME?

Tags: vba, excel

I really hope someone can help me with this.
I am trying to make a script that will delete existing named ranges and then define new ones based on a list in my worksheet.
The script looks like this at the moment.

```
Sub NamingRanges()

Worksheets("Input").Activate
Dim nm As Name

For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    nm.Delete
Next

Range("C6:Q9999").Select
Selection.CreateNames Top:=False, Left:=True, Bottom:=False, Right:=False
End Sub
```

When running the script, it gives me an error 1004 complaining about the name syntax. I have tried to put a "MsgBox nm" just before the nm.delete line and it returns =#NAME? in the dialog box. Even with no names in name manager.
I really hope someone will be able to help me with this.

Comment: in `Range("C6:Q9999")` where are the names ? and where do you define wach range per name ?

Comment: The names are defined for each row based on the text in column C. The defining of names is not a problem so far. It is the removing of prior names that gives me a headache at the moment.

Comment: I was able to remove all Names, unless you have some name which their scope is a `Worksheet` and not `Workbook`.

Comment: So it works for you?

Comment: yes, it's removing all my Names, but mune were defined with scope of `Workbook`

Comment: When I open the Name Manager there is nothing there. Just cycled through all worksheets (have 4). Nothing

Comment: i'ts because you deleted them with your `For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names` loop, no ?

Comment: Yes. But the script won't run. I just tried a script to delete hidden names(if any) I found on Microsoft's support site. It has the same problem. It returns a name defined as =#NAME? which is the wrong syntax.

Comment: your code works very nice with my tests, also creating the nre Named Ranges.  Are you sure they are all inside `ThisWorkbook` ? where you have your code ?

Comment: I am not completely sure, what you are asking? My scripts are stored as modules in the workbook

Comment: I think deleting a named range fails when the name contains certain kinds of errors - hidden names with errors or references to a "history" worksheet. If you start your code with `On Error Resume Next` the names will still get deleted and you won't see the error.

Comment: `MsgBox nm` will show the RefersTo property, I think. Try `MsgBox nm.Name` to display the true name. On my test workbook I have a masqued range named "_xlfn.COUNTIFS" that can't be deleted.

Comment: I wasn't able to delete the `_xlfn.COUNTIFS` named range using `.Delete` function (raised error 1004), but I was able to set is visible property to true and to delete it from the Name manager. (No idea how i got this named range in the first place, however).

Comment: I have now tried the solutions using the method in the answer below and "On Error Resume Next" and they both works. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the delete line

```
If InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, "=#NAME?") <1 Then nm.Delete
```

Comment: I will try that. I found out what caused the problem although I have no idea why. If I use the "IFERROR" function somewhere in the workbook and then run the script the error will occour.

Comment: Anyways. Your solution worked perfectly, even though it bugs me, why the error occured in the first time.

Comment: I just learned from another forum, that when you use eg. the IFERROR function in Excel 2007 or higher, it automatically stores a hidden name _xlfn.iferror which refers to =#NAME? to handle the non-compatibility in Excel 2003 or older.